# How to un-insert pages inserted into a vma with vm_insert_page?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I use `vm_insert_page` to insert a page to a userspace VMA, now I want to remove that page from that VMA. But I don't want the whole VMA got unmapped, just that exact page range only. Which kernel function should I call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any special kernel code in order to accomplish this. All you need is for user-space to call `munmap()` system call on the page that you want to unmap. Another option is to call `do_munmap()` directly from kernel. Look at the implementation of `munmap()` system call.

Comment: But can I do the same as `vm_insert_page()` without any special kernal code, too?

Comment: There are new kernel features being developed in that area, see about [remap_anon_range](http://lwn.net/Articles/615086/).

Comment: munmap() will call vmops->close() handler in the driver. Is there anything this handler should take care of for the mapping?